# Cartopy/Matplotlib savefig slow for lcc projections

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

We're in the process of migrating from Basemap to Cartoy and finding the `savefig` functionality to be a far too slow for our app, specifically when using the LambertConformal CRS. I ran a quick check using the the code snippet below and found that it takes about 10x as long to save using the LambertConformal projection vs PlateCarree. The plots within our app include numerous data layers including colormaps and contours but I found that `savefig` is consistently much slower  when using the LCC CRS. I saw that others suggested users set `PYPROJ_GLOBAL_CONTEXT=ON` but since our app is multithreaded that isn't an option for us. We can adopt the PlateCarree CRS as our default if needed but I thought I would check to see if other users in the community had similar issues.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

extent = [-10, 10, 50, 60]

lcc_projection = ccrs.LambertConformal(
    central_latitude=55,
    central_longitude=0,
)
pc_projection = ccrs.PlateCarree()

pc_plot = plt.axes(projection=pc_projection, facecolor="dimgrey")
pc_plot.set_extent(extent, crs=pc_projection)
pc_plot.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)

t = time.time()
plt.savefig('map_pc.png')
print(f"pc savefig time : {time.time() - t}") # Takes ~3s    

plt.close()

lcc_plot = plt.axes(projection=lcc_projection, facecolor="dimgrey")
lcc_plot.set_extent(extent, crs=pc_projection)
lcc_plot.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)

t = time.time()
plt.savefig('map_lcc.png')
print(f"lcc savefig time : {time.time() - t}")  # Takes ~30s     

plt.close()
```

Resulting images:

[PC plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppkmL.png)
[LCC Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTim5.png)

Comment: FYI, with my Raspberry Pi 4B, ...   pc savefig time : 17.724447011947632
lcc savefig time : 72.04993057250977  ;p